# Installing Windows Message Queue in Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, msmq

How can I install Windows Message Queue that can be accessed from another computer.
I've already installed MQ server, it displays correctly in Computer Management, but I was unable to connect to it from my Visual Studio Server Explorer. The error message was "Message Queueing has not been installed in this computer"

Answer (score 2):

Looks like MSMQ is not installed in your machine. Install it by following below steps :

1. Open Control Panel
2. Click Add/Remove programs
3. Click Add/Remove windows components
4. Check Message Queuing check box
5. Click Next

Answer (score 1):

Sound like you haven't installed MSMQ on the machine running Visual Studio? PS. I would have made this a comment, but for some reason I can't comment on your question.

Comment: I already installed MSMQ on the Visual Studio machine. I think it's got something to do with publishing the MSMQ in Domain Controller. I can't find info on how to this.

Answer (score 1):

I am also too new to server fault to comment.  However, Bernhard is correct.  There is a client component of MSMQ which will install the appropriate MSMQ MMC snap in which will allow you to administer MSMQ.  This component will need to be installed on your machine running Visual Studio before you can connect to MSMQ from it.

Answer (score 0):

On the server that we are using (Windows Server 2003 SP2), the procedure is slightly different from what aleroot described:

1. Open Control Panel
2. Click Add/Remove programs
3. Click Add/Remove windows components
4. Select Appication Server
5. Click Details...
6. Check Message Queuing check box and click OK
7. Click Next

Comment: Golly, are you still on 2003?